# Solar Sailing with Optical Amplification

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fiber-optics, solar-sails

The solar sail has been proposed as a means of carrying payloads into deep space without traditional thrusters. Most approaches seem to require a thin reflective chute that unfurls to a shape oriented about the sun.

Here it’s mentioned that reflection offers twice the momentum of absorption.

Source: [Solar Sail Discussion](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/webproj/212_spring_2015/Robert_Miller/physics.html)
$$p=\frac{2E}{c}$$
Suppose that a solar sail is modified such that it’s reflective side has a coating of the same Er(3+) used in infrared telco. amplifiers. Let’s also assume that evenly spaced LEDs and lithium batteries provide enough UV light to manifest the largest gain curve below:

[image: Source: Gain Curves]

Source: [RP-Photonics](https://www.rp-photonics.com/erbium_doped_fiber_amplifiers.html)

Would this approach amplify the Sun’s radiation pressure?

- If so, would the resulting momentum be caused by the light at the moment of reflection or would the light reflected backwards through the amplifying medium impart additional force?

[image: Reflection Clarification]
Where $I_2 > I_1$ in the magnified region.

- Finally, given that the highest gain from the amplification fiber is [near 16 dbm](https://thorbroadcast.com/product/16-dbm-edfa-optical-amplifier.html), does the thin film nature of the proposed design mean that insignificant amplification will occur?

Assuming amplification only occurs on incident light, a half-millimeter Erbium film gives the following equation for force:

$$F = \frac{2I}{c}$$
where $I$ is intensity in $\text{W/m}^2$

Amplified Force = $\frac{2I \times(1+ \log16 \times 0.0005)}{c}$

Comment: Conceivably you could increase the effect of radiation pressure. But it's highly unlikely this would be more effective than using a mass of rocket fuel equivalent to the batteries used for your system.

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps lithium batteries are less appropriate than an RTG (Radioisotope Thermoelectric generator). What forum is appropriate for discussion of power source?

Comment: Whatever you use to power the optical amplification is what's providing the extra propulsive power. Better to just find the most effective propulsion system and use the mass for that.

Comment: For rocket fuel, I think the energy offered is about $KE = {1/2}*m*{v^2}$. If you disregard the thermocouple step in RTG construction, radiation energy offered is closer to $E=m*{c^2}$ where m is the mass defect of Thorium or whatever material you chose. My latter claim should be substantiated [here](http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/phys250/modules/module%205/nuclear_decay.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If you could get this to work, then yes, this would increase the thrust provided by the solar sail.

However, the core problem with the idea is the energy source that would power this amplification; with the most common option for powering spacecraft, i.e. solar panels, this would be less efficient than just turning the solar-panel area into additional solar sails. You could also think of using e.g. a radioisotope thermal generator, but then your scheme is less effective than just powering a laser and using its radiation pressure for thrust (which, as you're probably aware, produces pretty negligible thrust).

Comment: Do you have any insight on how I would change the formula to calculate the momentum transfer with the thin film on? Specifically, does thrust not also come from the amplified light returning from the reflective layer to the sun?

Comment: @Human Creating thrust by creating light with some device on board is called a "photon rocket", "photon drive", and a few other things. What you propose to do here is to make the sail *also* function as a photon drive. But that leads you to a fundamental problem with photons drives: they are *vastly* power hungry. For instance, you get much more delta-vee/kW-hr from a ion drive (at the cost of having to carry fuel, of course).

Comment: @dmckee You mean propellant ;-).

Comment: Uhm ... yes. I guess I do.

Comment: @dmckee If the question _becomes_ how to best turn the on-board equipment into momentum using $KE = {1/2}*m*{v^2}$ it seems like a [Wakefield](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/1365Williams.pdf) accelerator would provide the most momentum. That question seems like a good fit for [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I assumed I could not turn all of my fuel into photons in the comment above.

Comment: @HumanFilament The energy inefficiency of a photon drive is just the limit of a general (but possibly surprising) trend: the energy cost of a unit of delta-v goes up with increasing exhaust velocity. For chemical fuels that cost is paid at the factory, but for photon drive, ion drive and other accelerator drives it is paid on board the space-craft. Photon drives and accelerator based drives have a lot of very cool properties, but you need to understand the tradeoffs.